# Example password_hash is not working everywhere

Tags: php, hash, echo

I am using this code to view a sample hash

```
<?php
    echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
?>
```

This is not working for my online server, BUT this works on local wamp server (I just turn this on for testing purpose)

Online hosting server parameters

```
PHP 5.2.17, 5.3.27, 5.4.24 & 5.5.9,
MySQL 5.5.25,
PostgreSQL  7.4.26 & 8.3.18,
Apache 2.2.17.
```

Dunno what's wrong

Comment: What PHP version is the online server currently? If it isn't 5.5 then that's why. It shows available versions, but which one is active? Use `phpinfo()` to see it.

Comment: For PHP >= 5.3.7 < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Testing 1,2,3... `<?php echo "Hello world.";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have php version 5.2 running on your server thats why... You need php version 5.5 or higher.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said too ;)

Comment: Is there any directive to change it?

Comment: You can only request your web host to upgrade it or you switch to another host

Comment: another option is for you to use another hashing algorithm like sha1 and crypt

Answer (score 1):

PHP Version 5.5.0 Required

```
<?php

 $hash = password_hash("xyz", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 echo $hash;

?>
```

For Reference, check http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php